# try-with-ressources can't create a new BufferedWriter after it's created and closed before

Tags: java, try-catch, bufferedreader

Program shows console menu and you can select things till you select (0) and the program exits.

First the program runs like expected and I'm able to select an option and call the `addPersonMenu()` or `deletePersonMenu()`. After every action in `showMainMenu()` the menu should rebuild on the console so the `showMainMenu()` method is called again in the main method. But this time it will throw an `IOException: Stream closed` and exit.

Debugging mode in eclipse shows that the `try-with-ressources` block is unable to open a new `BufferedReader`, although it should be closed properly and ressources should be set free.

Any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(!exit) {

        showMainMenu()
    }
}

private static void showMainMenu() {

    System.out.println("(1) Add new person");
    System.out.println("(2) Edit existing person");
    System.out.println("(3) Delete person");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("(5) Save changes");
    System.out.println("(0) Exit without saving");

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in))) {

        switch (Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())) {
        case (1):
            addPersonMenu();
            break;
        case (2):
            // editPersonMenu();
            break;
        case (3):
            deletePersonMenu();
            break;
        case (5):
            // saveChanges();
            break;
        case (0):
            exit();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Repeat!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        exit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `...although it should be closed properly and resources should be set free.` And that is exactly what happens. The `BufferedReader`, the `InputStreamReader` it wraps, and the `System.in` backing it are all properly closed. Unfortunately `System.in`, once closed, stays closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal: you close `System.in` in your method.

What you should do is something like this:

```
try (
    // open the resource here
) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        showMainMenu(line);
}
```

Especially since reopening a reader each time is wasteful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

System.in is an InputStream that implements Closeable. So after the first time when the try clause exits, the stream is closed and you get an IOException when it is utilized again.